# Conception of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we are hannded an ODE or rather an IVP of the form,

$f(x_{0})=a$ and $f^{'}(x)=F(x,f(x))$

Is it right to consider this as "Given that I start at $a$ and that my change is given by $F$ at each point, then my function is $f$, which is to be found.

Comment: Er, if not, what else ? What is the motivation of this question ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust Better safe then sorry?

Comment: Mh, you don't answer. I can't figure out what is unclear to you.

Comment: @Yves Daoust one statement is abouts sets and the other is in words(non formal words). One might have stumbled goin between them.

Comment: I'd rather say that the topic is a functional equation involving a derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is one interpretation that leads to the Euler polygonal path method and other one-step methods for numerical approximation.

The theoretical task behind the IVP is to find an interval $(x_s, x_f)$ that contains $x_0$ and among all the differentiable functions over that interval the ones that make $f'-F(x,f)$ the zero function, along with satisfying $f(x_0)-a=0$. This formulation also allows for multiple solutions.